# How to access rally api without login in .net framework?

Tags: .net, rally

I am not able to access rally API's in .net framework. Is there any way to do it without login?

How I can programmatically log in to Rally without credentials? I tried but it redirects to the login page first. And I want to login without the user entering credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You need to authenticate somehow- either with username/password or with an API Key.